# Headings in Latex not aligned

Tags: latex

I am creating a document in Latex with multiple headings after each other. However, the first one is further to the right than the following ones, like this:
[image]

The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\LARGE{HEADING 1}
\\
\LARGE{HEADING 2}
\\
\LARGE{HEADING 3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution thanks to Werner's comment (I first posted a solution that while working was not the optimal choice): this is because I am starting a new paragraph on the first line, and by default, the first line in a new paragraph is indented.

Solution: use \noindent as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\LARGE{HEADING 1}
\\
\LARGE{HEADING 2}
\\
\LARGE{HEADING 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, solution is, use `\noindent`.

Comment: The solution is to use `\section*{HEADING 1}`.